# Unable to initiate the asynchronous service invocation

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I am trying to make a remote procedure call of GWT RPC service. I get "Unable to initiate the asynchronous service invocation -- check the network connection.", but I don't have problem with connection.
The application runs in web mode in IE7 (in hosted mode it runs OK).

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `InvocationException` is thrown by `RemoteServiceProxy` when it is unable to send the XHR.  The exception's `getCause()` should have additional information about why the underlying `RequestBuilder` was unable to send the request.  The most common reason for not being able to fire the XHR is due to violating the [same-origin policy](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_Server.html#What_is_the_Same_Origin_Policy,_and_how_does_it_affect_GWT?).